# Jest & Material UI - Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I'm setting up a simple React project with Jest and running into a strange issue while importing `{ Button } from @material-ui/core`.  The error reads like I need to add `@material-ui` to my `transformIgnorePatterns` but that does not solve my problem.

The Error:

```
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    <removed full path>/node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Button/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default } from './Button';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

In a strange moment of brilliance (after unsuccessfully updating transformIgnorePatterns and a lot of Googling), I copied the contents of `node_moudles/@material-ui` into `node_modules/material_ui` (without the @ symbol) I updated the import and re-ran `jest`.

**The test passed.**

Why? I didn't even update the `transformIgnorePatterns` so why would it all of a sudden start transforming files in that new directory? Do I have an actual bug here or am I missing something in my configuration?

What can I do to get this working with `@material-ui`?

Here is my `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest'
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
            '<rootDir>/__mocks__/file-mock.js'
    },
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>*/public'],
    watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>*/public'],
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(@material-ui)/)'],
    globals: {
        __PATH_PREFIX__: ''
    },
    testURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/loadershim.js', '<rootDir>/jest.setup.js']
};
```

here is the failing test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { BatchBtn } from './common-btns';
import { data } from './btns.data';

describe('BatchBtn', () => {
    let component;

    const createShallow = () => {
        component = shallow(<BatchBtn {...data} />);
    };

    describe('Basic Functionality', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            createShallow();
        });

        test('component exists', () => {
            expect(component.exists()).toEqual(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Here are the installed packages in case I'm missing something:

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.17",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.17",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.1",
        "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.4.9",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.1",
        "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.9",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.1",
        "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.1",
        "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.1",
        "@storybook/react": "^6.4.1",
        "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.7",
        "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.6",
        "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
        "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.1",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.2",
        "eslint": "^7.20.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.0",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "jest": "^27.5.1",
        "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
        "speed-measure-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
        "storybook-addon-i18n": "^5.1.13",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.23.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.19.0",
        "jsbarcode": "^3.11.3",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "notistack": "^1.0.5",
        "print-js": "^1.6.0",
        "qs": "^6.10.1",
        "ramda": "^0.27.1",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-data-grid": "^7.0.0-canary.49",
        "react-datepicker": "^4.1.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
        "react-intl": "^5.12.5",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-select": "^4.3.1",
        "react-table": "^7.6.3",
        "styled-components": "^5.2.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in my `.babelrc`.  Two lines defining import plugins specifically for `@material-ui`.  I removed them and the tests began passing.  The project builds like it should so I find myself wondering if we ever needed those lines.